# Url parameters passing method

Tags: facebook, url, twitter, parameters, parameter-passing

How passing of url parameters works in facebook, twitter , youtube or other similar sites .

eg:

facebook http://www.facebook.com/**stackoverflowpage**

twitter: http://twitter.com/**StackOverflow**

you tube: http://www.youtube.com/user/**BBCWorldwide**

where bold ones are parameters( i believe those are parameters)

What i have seen in most websites is like this,

http://www.website.com/index.php?id=stackoverflow

then how those above websties is passing parameters in different method,how they are doing this?. Or whether when a new user is joined in those website a new file is created in their server.

eg:
http://www.facebook.com/**stackoverflowpage**
http://www.facebook.com/**stackoverflowpage.php**(or .aspx whatever methods)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is usually done by URL rewriting on ther server side. For example using .htaccess. A typical situation is: when a request of the form http://server.com/x/y comes in, it is rewritten as http://server.com/index.php?param1=x&param2=y and then passed on to the request processor (say, PHP).

Ref: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rewrite_engine

Comment: no, the above is only an example. url can be rewritten in a lot of ways depending on your app and/seo/url strategy

Comment: i am using htaccess in my websites. i am passing like this  http://www.website.com/index.php?id=stackoverflow -> http://www.website.com/Home?id=stackoverlfow ..but how how i can convert this url to http://www.website.com/stackoverflow using htacess

Comment: some examples: http://roshanbh.com.np/2008/03/url-rewriting-examples-htaccess.html

Comment: in your case, it would be: `RewriteRule ^stackoverflow$ index.php?id=stackoverflow` - this will rewrite `/stackoverflow` to `/index.php?id=stackoverflow`